# php JSON management: get a value from a decoded JSON object

Tags: php, iphone, itunes

I'm building a script to verify a transaction receipt with Apple's itunesconnect site (iphone dev) and I can't figure out where's the error in my code. I want to get the "status" value.

Please help me to find what am I doing wrong:

```
 <?php
    include("config.php");

    $receipt = json_encode(array("receipt-data" => $_GET["receipt"]));
    $response_json = do_post_request($url, $receipt);
    $response = json_decode($response_json);

    //Here's where I try to get the "status" key but doesn't work

    echo $response['status']; 
    //echo $response->status; 

    function do_post_request($url, $data)
    {
       //initialize cURL
     $ch = curl_init();

     // set the target url
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

     // howmany parameter to post
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

     // the receipt as parameter
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

     $result= curl_exec ($ch);
     curl_close ($ch);
     return $result;
    }

    ?>
```

and the answer to the iPhone looks like:

```
{"receipt":{"item_id":"327931059", "original_transaction_id":"1000000000074412", "bvrs":"1.0", "product_id":"sandy_01", "purchase_date":"2009-09-29 16:12:46 Etc/GMT", "quantity":"1", "bid":"com.latin3g.chicasexy1", "original_purchase_date":"2009-09-29 16:12:46 Etc/GMT", "transaction_id":"1000000000074412"}, "status":0}
```

but only "status":0 matters for now
- Thank's

Answer (score 0):

From the manual on [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/json_decode)

> Returns an object or if the optional
> assoc  parameter is TRUE, an
> associative array is instead returned.
> NULL is returned if the json  cannot
> be decoded or if the encoded data is
> deeper than the recursion limit.

So either send TRUE for the 2nd parameter

```
$response = json_decode($response_json, true);
```

Or access the decoded JSON with object syntax

```
$response->status;
```

### EDIT

Isolated test

```
$json = <<<JSON
{"receipt":{"item_id":"327931059", "original_transaction_id":"1000000000074412", "bvrs":"1.0", "product_id":"sandy_01", "purchase_date":"2009-09-29 16:12:46 Etc/GMT", "quantity":"1", "bid":"com.latin3g.chicasexy1", "original_purchase_date":"2009-09-29 16:12:46 Etc/GMT", "transaction_id":"1000000000074412"}, "status":0}
JSON;

$response = json_decode( $json );

echo $response->status;

$response2 = json_decode( $json, true );

echo $response2['status'];
```

Output is

> 00

Comment: Thanks, but still prints the whole array. Not getting the status value

Comment: Then something else is wrong.  I edited my answer to provide a test.

Comment: Can you see any error within the do_post_request() method or when I invoque it?, dont'n think so but your test code works only with you JSON sample, not the same with the $response_json varible

Comment: Should the script return a value even if I comment the echo instruction? Because it's extrange to me that the script returns the complete string again but without any echo or print command...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
$response->status;
```

Passing an optional param of true to the json_decode function will bring the results back as an associative array.

Have you checked your response_json variable to check that the data is being deserialised correctly? i.e:

```
var_dump($response);
```

Which should yield:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
["receipt"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (9) {
    ["item_id"]=>
    string(9) "327931059"
    ["original_transaction_id"]=>
    string(16) "1000000000074412"
    ["bvrs"]=>
    string(3) "1.0"
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(8) "sandy_01"
    ["purchase_date"]=>
    string(27) "2009-09-29 16:12:46 Etc/GMT"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["bid"]=>
    string(22) "com.latin3g.chicasexy1"
    ["original_purchase_date"]=>
    string(27) "2009-09-29 16:12:46 Etc/GMT"
    ["transaction_id"]=>
    string(16) "1000000000074412"
  }
  ["status"]=>
  int(0)
```

}

Comment: The problem remains, thats why I thought that it was just a syntax error

Comment: That's quite strange, the JSON data surely can't match what you've posted in that case. What does a var_dump() on $response_json give you?

Comment: responseString : {"receipt":{"item_id":"327931059", "original_transaction_id":"1000000000074715", "bvrs":"1.0", "product_id":"sandy_01", "purchase_date":"2009-09-29 23:16:35 Etc/GMT", "quantity":"1", "bid":"com.latin3g.chicasexy1", "original_purchase_date":"2009-09-29 23:16:35 Etc/GMT", "transaction_id":"1000000000074715"}, "status":0}string(13) "response_json"     Although I'm new in php, this is odd

Comment: I've got what I think is the problem behind this, the pho script returns data after I call this function $result= curl_exec ($ch); and it doesn't let me decode the answer, so should I put the post method in another file?

Comment: Slightly related question: See that Etc/GMT in the original_purchase_date? PHPs timezone_identifiers_list() does NOT list that among the choices! (They have Etc/GMT+1 and so on, always with +/- and a number.) How do we reliably convert this to a time? I could drop the Etc/GMT, but what if Apple changes the time zone down the road? Maybe it's enough to set up a Date object with the date/time parts, then call setTZByID using the time zone part, and finally use $date->getDate() and so on to manipulate as needed. (This is important to me because I am doing a subscription-based transaction.)